# c++ toolchain: modify default strip params

Tags: c++, bazel

after running bazel aquery command ,
I see following params for ccstrip

```
  "/usr/bin/strip",
         "-S",
         "-p",
         "-o",
         "bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/main/hello-world.stripped",
         "--strip-all",
         "bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/main/hello-world"
```

Here I see some default strip parameters like '-S"' and  "-p"

I am looking a way to customize the default parameters passed to strip.

Appreciate help.

I would like  a way to customize the default strip option.

Answer (score 1):

There is the [`--stripopt` command line flag](https://bazel.build/reference/command-line-reference#flag--stripopt). In fact, you appear to already be using because this flag because `--strip-all` is not a default strip flag. The downside of `--stipopt` is that it's only additive to the strip command. The only way to get rid of `-S` and `-p` would be [write to your own C++ toolchain](https://bazel.build/tutorials/ccp-toolchain-config), which is a bit of a drag. That said, you should be able to override `-S` (aka `--strip-debug`) by passing another "mode" flag like `--strip-all`.

Comment: Hi, I have created toolchain.  Could you please let me know which flags/features needs modification?

Comment: Hi, I have used option --stripopt=--strip-all in bazelrc, but this option is not overriding default -S flag.

Comment: Hi, https://cs.opensource.google/bazel/bazel/+/master:tools/cpp/unix_cc_toolchain_config.bzl;l=797;drc=2780fca1dcb197ebd16ddeeea6170e7b176a0315 . is this required feature?

Comment: No, that's for linking. You'd have to make a feature for the `STRIP_ACTION_NAME`.